# Android WebView iframe - Replace src

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, iframe, webview

I have a web application with a webview. There is a page with an iframe that contains pdf in it. Android doesn't support this and the url must be replaced with google docs url. Something like that: pdf url - `http://www.mypdf.com/pdf.pdf`, google docs pdf `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.mypdf.com/pdf.pdf`.

How can I replace the iframe src when loading the page? Maybe something with a javascript function loaded in the webview? An example would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always call the `JS` code on the page loaded into the `WebView` by using the following:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunc()");
```

Then just implement `myFunc` on your page which will do the necessary replacement.

Comment: I know that this is what I should do. But the problem is that I don't know javascript and also the page is not mine.

Comment: Yep, this is what I did and it worked. The answer is correct. I just suggest you to add the javascript function to you answer so people can see and use it. Here is what I did: 'javaScript = "javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=' + document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src;";
     webView.loadUrl(javaScript);'